# What does "skol'ko ya dolzhen" mean (I'm not sure how to spell this using the Cyrillic alphabet)?

Tags: phrase

I'm using Pimsleur to teach myself Russian and I've had "skol'ko ya dolzhen" stuck in my head. I can't remember what lesson I heard it in. All I know is that "skol'ko" means "how much."

Does anyone know what I'm talking about? I'm not great at the Cyrillic alphabet so I don't know how to properly type it, and if I did I could just put it into Google translate and solve all my problems!

Comment: @DK. I use this site http://russian.typeit.org/ sometimes, but when I have a sound that is a combination of English sounds (something like ж or щ) I don't know what to do to. Especially since щ, ш, and ч usually sound the same to me.

Comment: @DK.  Make it an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сколько я должен? *[skol'ko ya dolzhen]* 
It means "How much do I owe you?"

On the Pimsleur course this phrase should appear at lesson №10-15.